# How to create new sample library in LINQPad

Tags: linqpad

I am trying to figure out how to write a sample library in LINQPad.

Went on the official website and tried to google arround as well but couldn't find anything.

I am working on a small framework library for work and I would like to showcase the usage of the framework via some samples. I don't want to publicly distribute the samples, just want to be able to send them to other developers I am working with.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some sample library .zip files here:

> [LINQPad Sample Libraries](http://www.linqpad.net/RichClient/SampleLibraries.aspx)

Just unzip them and look at the contents.

It looks like all you have to do is just zip up a folder full of LINQPad scripts, and provide a `header.xml` file in the root of the zip file containing something like this:

```
<SampleLibrary>
    <Name>Name of your sample library</Name>
</SampleLibrary>
```

If you check the contents of some those libraries on that web page you'll notice that they also bundle the libraries used in the zip file, you should consider doing this as well so that the people you send the library to don't have to fix references in any of the samples before trying them.

Answer (score 1):

In the [latest beta](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx), you can create a sample library just by right-clicking a folder in **My Queries** and choosing **Create sample library**.